# How to insert UNICODE characters to SQL db?

Tags: php, python, sql, unicode

I want to build an universal database in which I will keep data from multiple countries so I will need to work with the **UNICODE** charset.

I need a little help in order to figure out which is the best way to work with stuff like that and how my queries will be affected ( some **sql example** queries from **php/python** for basic stuff like insert/update/select would also be great)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

just put a N infront of the string, something like `INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES(N"xxx")` and make sure your column type is nvarchar

Comment: Ok , and how do I read the value from the database after that ? Can I use SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE name = xxx  or I have to do name = N"xxx" somehow ?

Comment: @Alessandro nothing special you need to do when you are reading from the DB, where "xxx" would work

Comment: And if I have multiple values to insert ? INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES(N"xxx1","xxx2") or  (N"xxx1",N"xxx2") ?

Comment: N"xx1", N"xx2", the N prefix tells the DB where the following string should be treated as unicode string

Comment: Great , it's working . I have now my russian string in the database . But when I try to print it with PHP with the standard SQL query I get some ???????? instead of my string : Смотреть

Comment: @Alessandro not a PHP expert. guess i will leave that part to others :(

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing special you need to do.

with php you can do... query("SET NAMES utf8");